# cocos2dx scheduleUpdateWithPriorityLua

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to know how to use this API,and it's perfect to set a example for me.
Thank you very much!

There is no introduction for it,and I want to know its' usage,and the difference with schedule update.

Comment: This api is designed for lua. Do you mean how to use it in lua?

Comment: YES,I had learned how to design iOS app,but now I work as a mobilephone-gamecoder.I'm unfamiliar with lua,and the official document is not available.